# Looping a multi string in r

Tags: json, r, loops

I have a Json formatted multiline txt file.

I would like to separate each string into a new txt file. I know how to separate each string one at a time (below) but I have about 65 string, so looping is preferred. What is the best way forward? The reason I am doing this is because I want to manipulate the elements as a list format.

```
string <- file("small copy.txt", "rt")
class(string)

#Looping (Step 2)
a <- readLines(string, 2)
a

# Save to a new text file
fileConn <-file("new.txt")
writeLines(a, fileConn)
close(fileConn)

# read the new Text file. 
json_data <- fromJSON(file="new.txt")
class(json_data)
unlist(json_data)
```

I can't add anymore lines because it is too long. But each string is about this long. Only the values change. The structure is the same. I would like to know how I can loop the process in a way that allows me to have x number of new text file with one string each in it.

```
 " {\"NonlightningIndices\":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],\"LightningIndices\":[],\"SelectedAction\":2,\"State\":{\"Features\":{\"Data\":[28.0,79.0,0.599999964237213,19.0,7.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,12.0,2.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]}},\"Actions\":[{\"Features\":{\"Data\":[4.0,4.0,2.0,3.0,0.0,2.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.939884518674621,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.09808921439463,0.744152363249732,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.539038182688179,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.451792079939885,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.877180883940764,0.539796338155356,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.413997847430786,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.08484538298999,1.29385392975455,0.0054082469529275,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.34875511885264,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.71694497358585,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0438641064326508,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.54820792006012,0.0,1.10749608495373,1.13223270324941,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,4.87124723629749,1.69476274441702,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.078870537789237,0.924076678684348,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.2160858549049,0.0,2.61278406016796,4.16759630538064,0.463447798805987,0.0,0.0,5.09009923782957,0.114512389494682,0.0759233213156518,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.33321496326392,0.0,4.57468683114717,0.0,2.53655220119401,0.0,0.0,3.90990076217043,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,5.45069918183118]}},{\"Features\":{\"Data\":[0.0,2.0,5.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,9.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0786903299597191,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.411142420481752,0.0,0.152980983670504,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.122333494063463,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.448099617018257,0.55266314906073,0.0,0.378327373308482,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.556679374622303,1.55059449965162,0.0,0.390001313061295,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.761574329997164,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,2.81769759145642,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0396007816804909,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.498062911279442,1.16602345744291,0.381865009442935,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0667198352218605,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.382821089666168,0.497158097079998,0.585228174382118,1.38554709260885,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.22851942492077,0.198824888322345,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.792282699828043,0.0,2.00281795809221,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.488204788462914,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.207717300171957,0.0,1.13238192085785,1.1516534751616,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.73020426295513,1.31211168442192,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.861438662226933,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,6.16718193723314,0.0,2.10592195666222,2.7688227383647,0.475947800312036,0.0,0.0,3.89876002810124,0.0,0.071841502551207,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.17634019269456,0.0,2.82299111489359,0.0,2.52405219968796,0.0,0.0,3.38451575851508,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.27365678040613]}},{\"Features\":{\"Data\":[0.0,3.0,3.0,0.0,8.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.184757200927663,0.0,0.0,0.52227693765707,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.90909315676036,0.87757102440966,0.0,0.815242799072337,0.0,0.0,1.10162685884891,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.736516254770373,3.76653236862878,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.376096203494019,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.116383751398929,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0830214316132467,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.570693322613913,1.21835011966569,0.974072781209452,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.916978568386753,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.783697265855355,2.26257953439618,0.200746851524004,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.19133730797977,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.191337307979766,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,4.0,2.0519455270139,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.659466857833436,0.0,0.462684998436592,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.99696345968727,3.1762807646468,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.9168225672559,0.0,0.537315001563408,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.431513492885736,0.0,2.87800349321242,0.48057032420691,1.80241929529117,0.0,0.0,5.37141939831532,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.36529398391662,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.19758070470883,0.0,0.0,0.86095386861557,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0118552152178836]}},{\"Features\":{\"Data\":[0.0,6.0,0.0,0.0,16.0,0.0,6.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0695085704366688,0.0732613552182185,0.204019459347982,0.0,0.0,0.597373481973216,0.122510434558433,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.829533311522673,0.0,2.10066621881181,0.721784069983707,0.795980540652018,0.0,0.0,1.15603437525546,1.42112291365569,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.923874545706,0.0,5.50279646194453,0.100096121989931,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.24659214277132,0.456366651785877,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.24659214277132,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.72789830807141,1.33694708298613,0.107724789325011,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.23302501989508,2.0,1.18553247134074,0.012577050602636,0.0,0.0,0.393568282436165,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.393568282436165,0.0,1.32702874880699,0.0992463890689407,0.819571259504252,0.0,0.0,2.29094339825907,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.29094339825907,0.0,0.0216529747525163,0.103301139817455,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.39440910912117,2.64139994226136,0.886757131957011,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.64466756291234,1.0,1.18973827895237,0.00559690564027665,0.0,0.0,1.41457891248988,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.90598502135835,0.0,0.367859387250647,0.235616328830882,2.05928624653397,0.0,0.0,0.900909406814879,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.409503297946411,0.0,0.0,0.156546438270318,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.890528454826197,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.736747631124021,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.736747631124021,0.0,0.0,1.13516446682763,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.270437807621918,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.270437807621918,0.0,2.63214061274935,0.114702563591587,0.102968537718868,0.0,0.0,2.99281456125406,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.99281456125406]}},{\"Features\":{\"Data\":[3.0,3.0,1.0,3.0,3.0,9.0,2.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.109483497583805,0.0,0.531588632631924,0.0,0.0,0.606201098177325,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.72209173437177,0.0,0.468411367368075,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.131024902864609,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.58278762739389,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.218143106547861,1.54969081971071,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.393798901822676,0.588051108572859,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.178622985732,0.898615451465495,0.118847064263758,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.944342057296115,1.28092398856253,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.54016339764414,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0556579427038854,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.156185336018272,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.118089749913488,1.09119287869259,1.98839186391157,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.407621568806719,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.1395122431916,0.512041029027553,1.03266437090715,1.03542974444441,0.181991429103966,0.0,0.0,1.75643402500444,0.0,0.0115199917105305,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.42720297650418,0.0,1.4681118688126,0.0,0.513511392175225,0.0,0.0,0.6619212429853,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.11158821815324,0.0,1.39674173529758,1.32947767482444,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.20923334835311,0.0,2.13541750370083,1.31265860253515,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.545907821503027,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.816308554236357,0.0,1.09104811795301,2.20358691393224,0.45377681008426,0.0,0.0,2.87375670492857,0.0,0.0349506179797238,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.52986629729269,0.0,2.32860667522918,0.0,1.85072036863655,0.0,0.0,2.70788802708169,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.64819861235533]}},{\"Features\":{\"Data\":[2.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,4.0,2.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.114479034402412,0.0,0.0,0.248287910422655,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.458281365704629,0.0,0.862935876980988,0.0,0.826322911719018,0.0,0.0,1.08722437311034,0.273980721207288,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.31474352567036,0.0,3.72468139412127,0.0,0.0591980538785701,0.0,0.0,0.664487716467009,0.367346088594686,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.95165650274628,0.0,0.209244387661066,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.209244387661066,0.0,0.0,0.0534556323080033,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.286741384549499,1.21763488507861,0.771259171502368,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.01767834568565,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.70676898488872,2.21034257189029,0.0927455803580035,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.26604852808309,0.340994844512378,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.06607421821766,0.0,0.054265517074708,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.74807513493194,0.0116329892539229,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.18494040331473,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.717151612348486,1.9194292379404,0.47504360028316,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0635207671376004,0.0,0.47256058757968,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.289338018213295,0.582400366025234,0.156962927293438,0.669317256585697,0.0,0.0,2.73869859308251,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.219065763227434,0.0,0.474223355562446,0.0,0.0,0.124016117175887,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.11647272648455,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.377508691973357,0.0,0.0616635398016962,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.864547861416495,0.0,1.13545213858351,1.73489563211824,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.28932909934806,0.0,0.280835469303894,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.13545213858351,0.0,1.91414140185992,0.704004466882865,0.800076507022226,0.0,0.0,2.8472970938583,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.18836378096313,0.0,1.08585859814008,0.0,1.05638288082963,0.0,0.0,1.29358110934119,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.81163621903687]}},{\"Features\":{\"Data\":[4.0,4.0,4.0,1.0,6.0,2.0,6.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.59329757597368,0.999322651166574,0.883232692894983,0.0,0.0,1.10431382742967,1.10721172293332,0.0742334281924989,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.59329757597368,0.0,5.67921347006218,0.789922760320107,0.116767307105017,0.0,0.0,2.65579325936668,0.892788277066677,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.35251580789306,0.0,1.02545508398132,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.352152746150428,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,4.1850132200747,0.622991308573116,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.697296762946348,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.4278802656418,0.927694283264635,0.163641432868928,0.401327975473868,0.523307258806202,0.0,0.0,2.58927988131231,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.757810699485824,1.15914214967573,0.14758964213939,0.0,0.476692741193798,0.0,0.0,0.346894082712682,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.14758964213939,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.2057895748998,2.82694512353314,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.04379494383268,0.0,0.228469808861153,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,4.56400375188159,1.25845934652245,0.684420764941867,0.787742034142953,0.193201813955338,0.0,0.0,1.66556470532409,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.30080050047341,0.654704220537193,1.31494052692521,0.0,0.806798186044662,0.0,0.0,0.575355460138141,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.450396301769975,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.274797060193193,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.503949010360804,0.0,1.00043742449549,0.121351845020261,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.800126384991792,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.000201283637429739,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.944080394698764,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]}},{\"Features\":{\"Data\":[2.0,2.0,2.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.272133451464892,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.58531719458049,0.364812141129821,0.431434625120592,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.472792602264747,0.620019047422307,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.19922970878934,0.0,9.05847199836593,2.25042499244611,1.79369352936747,0.0,0.0,5.30035850082451,1.52720739773525,0.0810647742772507,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,7.80077029121066,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.268410973648211,0.757546880483783,0.558901358878714,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.710924103824146,0.748120783864193,1.70738131919459,0.715140383952877,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.328251165772564,0.0,0.291294153996938,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.289075896175854,0.0,2.03688803790544,1.41185652439148,1.77487184551194,0.0,0.0,2.13099052714532,0.0,0.00762202430350499,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.61350318786339,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.708278110600803,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.275190131886792,0.0,0.14088588410651,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.671748834227436,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.58226111800487,0.55797871509449,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.56865097203017,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.38649681213661,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]}},{\"Features\":{\"Data\":[3.0,3.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,8.0,10.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.344765483669486,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.27558222923464,0.0,3.7925999892559,0.414345211524559,0.505745197836686,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.562729216897313,0.550037894230724,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.7210423818232,0.0,3.65576761308294,2.00245551463723,0.78676297501535,0.0,0.0,3.62935394501789,1.43118156021122,0.0432713739085531,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.42938167391135,0.0,4.7987186048796,0.0,0.720459604601606,0.0,0.0,1.34539766061443,0.00608922289147126,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.2045753278008,0.0,1.05241302192194,0.68222977998087,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.42525357787784,0.797763230732279,1.88460357677526,0.60780247307355,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0596872248914957,0.0,0.395002496915062,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.04921133029773,0.878083979270083,0.471131710414871,0.99694396525792,0.281694993795999,0.0,0.0,1.97731748011525,0.0,0.0116882349456615,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.13733669074704,0.0,0.885710027196786,0.0,1.66725199882089,0.0,0.0,0.0598535463291507,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.69687401929258,0.0,0.0,0.596163214274655,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0607427690148167,0.789078043494907,0.0,0.178043562852026,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.940312775108504,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.535074746502731,0.61781150138347,0.522016278399192,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.812860445811871,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.49647847141974,0.0,0.0380852299294706,0.0,0.0,2.17521692211141,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]}}]}"

 "{\"NonlightningIndices\":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],\"LightningIndices\":[],\"SelectedAction\":1,\"State\":{\"Features\":{\"Data\":[29.0,87.0,0.199999988079071,21.0,6.0,3.0,1.0,0.0,9.0,2.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]}},\"Actions\":[{\"Features\":{\"Data\":[4.0,4.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.967271214425,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.19347272873972,0.532627846431111,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.610880309622021,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.409598810442613,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.10396852888709,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.182491786647411,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.735287527948186,1.30331661986825,0.0,0.0,0.304396436866815,0.0,1.0,0.230574297328125,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.233325357043424,0.0,1.05839544647961,0.0,0.0,0.153007314297959,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.862296054914952,0.0,2.59989034724162,0.759479375118069,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0157477506375597,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.221196215130451,0.0,7.10461267908334,0.71060758850654,0.0,0.167000271329625,0.0,0.0,0.447252223808276,0.98425224936244,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.90017330721905,0.0,3.58194098717305,3.16632965012563,0.359212243328456,0.19310419085819,0.0,2.93001477992437,1.3221734788636,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.55856488680092,0.0,4.208335764101,1.36358338624975,1.64078775667154,0.0,0.0,4.06998522007563,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,5.81484536844859]}},{\"Features\":{\"Data\":[0.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,12.0,0.0,9.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.563342769711105,0.14922047396535,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.92311386248307,0.0,0.436657230288895,0.292589809888545,0.0,1.0,0.122198126927604,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.27066047401507,0.0,0.0,0.126956038600049,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.466449530872156,1.39174850937943,0.0,0.0,0.233990404175585,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.535063631409855,1.71933358475141,0.0444493442168773,0.0,0.197243273370471,0.0,0.0,0.877801873072395,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.08689207875044,0.072724691859667,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.952884456456208,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.952884456456208,0.0,0.81031779853856,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0344232726459453,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.197758476232372,0.482312773938703,2.79968046646494,0.28597197194638,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.457951179538371,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.67034327196778,0.516174063779287,1.20575147415962,1.20758038567643,0.269427618553346,0.0,0.0,1.10310656110799,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.999999999999999,0.655407312157884,0.499471487921696,0.0,0.0,0.972882467584648,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0759890286926427,0.0,2.09633685664798,0.815981192192423,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.00159324796344052,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.00954424833810024,0.0,2.91193077058695,0.523689574658405,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.506032299852243,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.12235400346175,0.0,0.784234124222518,1.92981219013765,0.140188812556691,0.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,2.0,0.46438333715428,1.09091208096827,0.0,0.0,1.97112651485115,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.97112651485115]}},{\"Features\":{\"Data\":[0.0,3.0,2.0,2.0,9.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.130377947841013,0.0,0.0,0.136286236615577,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.673080202711636,0.0,0.0,0.583795224890157,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.43415281067927,0.0,0.0613755957477646,0.00968695219094316,0.0,0.0684815192859497,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0391945004877003,0.0,0.413164628235241,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.5565534772133,0.0,0.0,0.135166253699587,0.499130871723474,0.0,0.74005879437705,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.873586361091797,1.74957392233909,0.0,0.0,0.264210758894615,0.0,0.0582135965960254,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.58079753763689,0.0,0.0,0.00153286585759501,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0780192184589728,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.949827102879308,1.29748801352193,0.302035798211935,0.0,0.186244050845672,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.620033058815593,2.26710788625528,0.847130929634542,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.174340799229,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.174340799228995,0.0,0.0929608010134425,0.152869070365457,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,4.51381424282066,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.641906631330267,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,4.05612850220604,1.96085706429239,0.116846562857012,0.0,0.0,1.72134384023757,0.0,0.280074150210761,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.721343840237568,0.0,0.366576502329014,1.73710713749567,0.973656699575889,0.0,0.0,3.64928266754674,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.10431536053344,0.0,2.64139978119838,0.0,0.909496737567099,0.0,0.0,0.455032692986697,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]}},{\"Features\":{\"Data\":[0.0,6.0,0.0,0.0,12.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.435743770218028,0.0,0.0536177400889474,0.0,0.0,0.250190714904485,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.250190714904485,0.0,1.00181101462474,0.0,0.80657275506729,0.671121117468115,0.0,1.30812313367215,0.732281156271011,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.31017611617401,0.0,6.0,0.162370670250217,0.139809504843763,0.328878882531885,0.0,1.44122164450912,0.814081148033547,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.53304517013818,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.82322750146823,1.62874337944964,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.13798660532399,2.33620774288709,1.11606827092279,0.0273239335809844,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.419192229077247,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.833192367538785,0.0,1.85020947010914,1.01060546152008,0.784362318972823,0.0,0.0,2.07505968791525,0.0344454666181948,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.14799081224554,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.19825833572589,2.76805659969547,0.581909993323405,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.84052755748189,2.01417519894957,0.773424934498476,0.0108202287905856,0.0,0.0,1.18351222630537,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.769334205041459,0.0,1.43848602030898,1.327138703291,1.12175868414654,0.0,0.0,1.80604559297821,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.22022361424212,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0209730408712075,0.418090006676595,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.944079783195103,0.0277051656540633,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.561513979691024,0.582686793863375,0.0557348345090641,0.0,0.0,0.935846999715415,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.935846999715415]}},{\"Features\":{\"Data\":[2.0,2.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.760789871171889,0.284840782568494,0.0,1.15912036398353,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.082828886802,0.0,2.93246629709704,0.0,0.239210128828111,0.327939151145646,0.0,0.840879636016469,0.255631235428715,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.84963741029505,0.0,0.644761270238819,0.0,0.0,0.0549361006975404,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.644761270238819,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.78021211160955,0.0188061338788185,0.0,0.271361486184561,0.0,0.0,0.691189385474799,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0381472966702208,0.562162951859714,2.41185796474241,0.00230611677545991,0.0,0.0609224794037588,0.0,0.42348414602128,0.944476698325121,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.427450274551072,0.440643070679767,0.216587290999384,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.57651585397872,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.81075343562808,0.892363331406227,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.00283747396750503,0.0853523484423467,0.621277269854386,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.12537108972856,0.463599133332876,0.794327176922341,0.620728936563497,0.497515659890769,0.0,0.0,1.77878594671466,0.0233503323290182,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.831803771714286,0.533594844127642,1.1428177339257,0.0,0.502484340109231,0.0,0.0,0.748943992430397,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.000140424293282402,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,5.17246659956313,1.53000007975713,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.399700778303967,0.0,0.378722730145614,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.236567853199238,1.80535411134324,0.140057281549847,0.0,0.0,1.65389032023655,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.54597186120913,0.0,1.80721202349799,0.130441290275627,0.828200139415196,0.0,0.0,1.41584148834692,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.33081089273589,0.0,0.0498298182830309,0.0,0.0317425790349571,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.123217246054979]}},{\"Features\":{\"Data\":[2.0,2.0,0.0,1.0,8.0,7.0,10.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.83226163819151,0.0225329294029727,0.606868177276171,0.415848423572654,0.0,1.0,0.510385610594739,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.00812480051864,0.0,4.23266082295984,0.207440355471339,0.393131822723829,0.479183840454676,0.0,1.05443366929313,1.42512840810783,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.41562296412416,0.0,2.01610232743039,0.356937818136052,0.0,0.10496773597267,0.0,0.94556633070687,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.584377035875842,0.0,1.32955407859058,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0623867714320004,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.634325326513543,0.375033376457717,2.35216758594904,0.235183084573486,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.04579637696327,0.57346592047594,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.991875199481355,0.64063750822945,0.871578873392179,0.928748756537094,0.406849976796645,0.0,0.0,1.34766092431746,0.0186896043341629,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.24572520086436,0.0,1.18674199890604,0.337612081565701,0.593150023203355,0.0,0.0,1.27110064807629,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.21458155355536,0.0,1.77326369675363,0.631678277180419,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.00318914719653939,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.63077819044143,0.620297688988779,2.83745934307583,0.141385962338043,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.00948060867055159,0.0,0.36095816089552,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.659220123465174,0.364031426324052,0.563006584795868,1.33784667732091,0.0469599846680629,0.0,0.0,1.83222124315475,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.46025370836072,0.0,1.63004485551422,0.313140877784402,0.953040015331937,0.0,0.0,0.994943646956615,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.62382369204833,0.0,0.0,0.226935760481539,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.449065550714989,0.0,0.143171691301017,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0334532964759791,0.0,0.0487733575601043,0.220121022484542,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0487733575601043,0.0,0.183213145579741,0.0404363967235006,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.544592928824329,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]}},{\"Features\":{\"Data\":[3.0,3.0,4.0,1.0,6.0,2.0,5.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.79667151529779,0.100106184244997,0.464950235511096,0.314189121810292,0.0,1.0,0.398756553549238,0.120959550274082,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.79667151529779,0.0,3.65016662036593,0.55671942646703,0.535049764488904,0.520675205968127,0.0,1.11687236160908,1.60124344645076,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.907197301519285,0.0,3.73041493696292,0.824395977061583,0.0,0.165135672221581,0.0,1.44549122266736,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.47338425580957,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.78484478965427,0.194479443981061,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.682626956374692,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.55919681504747,0.751468262906828,0.398826111190465,1.22720599164616,0.335755139176872,0.0,0.0,1.67076695913283,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.45208997449287,0.712432269290823,0.95695981781691,0.0,0.685428346195491,0.0,0.0,1.72023541586,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.95695981781691,0.0,0.614417154440565,0.0,0.0957738611624419,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.614417154440565,0.0,2.84557750674243,1.03425420382941,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.196413493351226,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.19497721121467,0.815362400760398,1.17408007711504,0.850634718199919,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.04663404073073,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.997064483947201,0.720737067041948,0.335380129732644,0.212204054569845,0.684849879089775,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0170343386644193,0.0,0.712661340681031,0.0,0.19819277437542,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0310071317492553,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]}}]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely don't need to write into a file and read from it.
`fromJSON` can take strings as input.

Now to loop over a list while keeping the `list` format, `lapply` is the way.
I don't have any JSON file to test it but this should work:

```
a <- readLines("small copy.txt")
json_data <- lapply(a, fromJSON)
```

It's also surprising that the last step of your code would be to unlist the data when you say you would like to "manipulate the elements as a list format".

Comment: I tried this approach, but this doesn't quite work because the txt file is in a naive json format. The data is only json formatted within each string. So fromJson() only reads the first line and ignore everything else.

The final unlist() is just to show it works.

Comment: readLines reads line by line, if what you say is correct, `a` should be a list of json formatted strings. After that, using `lapply` makes a call to `fromJSON` for each one of these strings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks SRenan, I managed to solve my question and shortened my work flow with your help. Somehow, R returned saying that that it was empty.

```
a<- readLines("small copy.txt")
json_data <- lapply(a, fromJSON)
Error: no data to parse
```

But I added the paste() and that worked out well. For some reason it works when you concatenate the vectors together after converting to character.

```
a<- paste(readLines("small copy.txt"), collapse="",  sep = "\r")
json_data <- lapply(a, fromJSON)   
class(json_data)
[1] "list"
```

I am not sure why, but it solved my problem!